# AngularJS - How to set input value different than ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set the ng-model of an element as, lets say, person, and the input value of that element to be person.Name...but I am not being able to, can u tell me the way to achieve this?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.project.parentProject"
    value={{model.project.parentProject.Name}}></input>
```

This does not work as for some reason `model.project.parentProject` puts itself over everything...help¿

Comment: <input type=text ng-model="person.Name"></input> should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `ng-model` and whatever you assign the model in the controller gets picked up as the value, eg:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel" />

$scope.myModel = "Test";
```

`value` is now `Test`

Comment: This is not what the OP was asking.